# Find the most frequent value ignoring everything after '(' within it

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to find the most frequent string ignoring everything after `(` within it.

So, how it should work. If I've got the strings:

```
England (88)
Iceland (100) 
Iceland (77) 
England (88)
Denmark (15) 
Iceland (18)
```

It should return

```
Iceland
```

because it's the most frequent country here and no matter that as a string England (88) is going to pretend.

Unfortunately, my query returns

```
England(88)
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/857a3/2)

I've been thinking to do it by 2 steps:

1. truncate every country string
2. do script that I already written.

But I failed on the first step.

Comment: I am sorry, but all the answers is not going to work in Android:       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: INSTR

Comment: Wow, the stripped down android version is quite limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Fiddle is acting up, so can't test, but I'd think you could use `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()` to isolate the portion left of the first `(`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(X,1,INSTR(X,'(')-1) AS HUS 
FROM tt 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(X,1,INSTR(X,'(')-1) 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Edit: Tested on https://sqliteonline.com/ and it returns `Iceland` as expected: [Fiddle](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-589c9ab1ddb68334be4fd76d84299b39d6920363e62a574646).

Comment: thanx a lot, but it is not working in Android because Android SQLite doesn't have INSTR function :(

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: So the base SQLite has it as of 3.7.15, but I guess Android version is stripped down, no Regex, no `INSTR()`. Guess you'll have to do this outside of the database.

Comment: thank you. I can do this. Just need to change my SQLite table.

Comment: @Иван That'd be ideal, storing the country in a separate field is better design and makes a lot of things easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bunch of string manipulation, which is rather cumbersome in SQLite.  Here is one approach:

```
select trim(substr(str, 1, instr(str, '(') - 1)) as country,
       sum(cast(replace(substr(str + 1, instr(str, '('), ')', '') as int))
from t
group by trim(substr(str, 1, instr(str, '(') - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a bullet-proof, whether you have `'('` in your text or not

```
select      rtrim(substr(mycolumn,1,instr(mycolumn || '(','(')-1))
from        mytable
group by    rtrim(substr(mycolumn,1,instr(mycolumn || '(','(')-1))    
order by    count(*) desc
limit       1
```

Comment: could it be without 'instr', because I do not have it in Android

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solutions based on **replace**, **rtrim** and potentially **replicate**

```
select      rtrim(substr(replace(mycolumn,'(',replicate(' ',50)),1,50))
from        mytable
group by    rtrim(substr(replace(mycolumn,'(',replicate(' ',50)),1,50))
order by    count(*) desc
limit       1
;
```

---

```
select      rtrim(substr(replace(mycolumn,'(','                                                  '),1,50))
from        mytable
group by    rtrim(substr(replace(mycolumn,'(','                                                  '),1,50))
order by    count(*) desc
limit       1
;
```